# Apache Shiro No FilterChainResolver configured. Returning original FilterChain

Tags: jsf-2, shiro

I was configuring my application to use apache shiro security, However, I keep getting the following in my log output:

```
DEBUG o.a.s.w.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter - No FilterChainResolver configured.  Returning original FilterChain.
```

My .ini file looks like this at the moment:

```
    [main]
cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

authc = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter

authc.loginUrl = /login.xhtml

[users]
admin = password

[urls]
/login.xhtml = authc
/logout = logout
/secured/** = authc
```

The relevant snippet from my web.xml is as follows:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

I am using Apache Shiro 1.2 on a tomcat 7 container
Strange that there are not so many questions addressing this issue, what did I overlook?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was using a blank shiro.ini file. I rectified this and now I can see shiro is catching the write URLs